# How to Display an image file in ajax from MongoDB

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, mongodb, gridfs

Im new in mongoDB GridFs Image Store..
In my project I need to display the product images, that's returned from MongoDB, Im using ajax response to get Json Image array from MongoDB
My Json array fromat is :

```
[
{
 "_id" : "1001",
 "chunkSize" : NumberLong(262144),
  "length" : NumberLong(19642),
  "md5" : "2ee6b6adec30c23c6d7bff6a835a956b",
  "filename" : "photo3.jpg",
  "contentType" : null,
  "uploadDate" : ISODate("2013-11-04T19:54:49.782Z"),
  "aliases" : null
},
{
  "_id" : "1002",
  "chunkSize" : NumberLong(262145),
  "length" : NumberLong(19643),
  "md5" : "fafa5efeaf3cbe3b23b2748d13e629a1",
  "filename" : "photo2.jpg",
  "contentType" : null,
  "uploadDate" : ISODate("2013-11-04T19:54:49.782Z"),
  "aliases" : null
},
{
  "_id" : "1003",
  "chunkSize" : NumberLong(262145),
  "length" : NumberLong(19643),
  "md5" : "9d377b10ce778c4938b3c7e2c63a229a",
  "filename" : "photo1.jpg",
   "contentType" : null,
  "uploadDate" : ISODate("2013-11-04T19:54:49.782Z"),

}
]
```

How to display image file in img.src in jquery
Thanks in Advance